# Avoiding Data duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I am New to php and programming as well.

I have a variable in an SQL query-based while loop. Below

```
switch ($command) {
    case "country":
        $statement = "SELECT w_id,w_name FROM wards ORDER BY w_id ASC";
        $dt = mysqli_query($conn, $statement);
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($dt)) {
            echo $result1 = "<option value=" . $result['w_id'] . ">" . $result['w_name'] . "</option>";
        }
        break;
}

exit();
```

The loop works just fine butthe variable contains duplicate strings.

How do I prevent duplicate row variables echoing in my while loop with PHP?

Comment: PHP is a general-purpose scripting language, MySQL is an implementation of SQL which is short for Structured Query Language.  You are asking how to do it in PHP, but it's easier to do it in SQL.  (That's probably the reason the current two answers explan how to do it in SQL.)

Comment: Why not write some code to achieve that? Also, maybe it could be good to put a `UNIQUE`  index on your table such that duplicated data isn't even stored there?

Answer (score 0):

That means you have duplicate rows in your DB, if you'd like to retrieve unique values, you could try a "group by" statement.

```
SELECT w_id, w_name FROM wards GROUP BY  w_name, w_id ORDER BY w_id ASC
```

It's a good practice indenting your code so you don't get confused in later reviews :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql query by using distinct keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT w_id, w_name FROM wards ORDER BY w_id ASC
```

This will prevent fetching duplicate rows from your DB.
Please see the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp